# Como inserir registros através de cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, cursor

Preciso inserir registros únicos por um campo que possui o identificador único, com isto estou usando cursor; entretanto, o identificador único não vai acrescentando de acordo com as inserções.

**ERRO:** Está duplicando e insere somente o primeiro registro.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
USE NESKI_DBA_ERP
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Declaração de variáveis que serão atribuidas no insert.

DECLARE 
 @ETQ_ID                          AS INT    ,
 @FIL_CODIGO                      AS NUMERIC,
 @PRO_CODIGO                      AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIAL               AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIALPRODUCAO       AS NUMERIC, 
 @ETQ_ESTOQUEMINIMO               AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_ESTOQUEMAXIMO               AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_ESTOQUECOMPRADO             AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_VALORULTIMOCUSTO            AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRA            AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDO           AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIO        AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRAMEDIO       AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDOMEDIO      AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIOMEDIO   AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_DATAULTIMAVENDA             AS DATE   ,
 @ETQ_VALORULTIMAVENDA            AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_QUANTIDADEVENDIDA           AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_DATAULTIMACOMPRA            AS DATE   ,
 @ETQ_VALORULTIMACOMPRA           AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_QUANTIDADECOMPRADA          AS NUMERIC,
 @ETQ_DATAALTERACAO               AS DATE   ;

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 -- Criação de um cursor

 DECLARE meuCursor CURSOR
 FOR
    SELECT '001',
           Substring(CODPRO,2,6),
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           0,
           Convert(date,GetDate(),108),
           0,
           0,
           Convert(date,GetDate(),108),
           0,
           0,
           Convert(date,GetDate(),108) 
      FROM SAPIENS_HOM.dbo.E075PRO
     WHERE CodFam in ('010', '015', '020', '025', '030', '040',
                     '042', '050', '052', '055', '060', '070',
                     '071', '075', '076', '077', '078', '100', 
                     '110', '120', '130', '140', '153', '160', 
                     '170', '180', '185', '190', '195', '115', 
                     '105', '199', '106', '125', '135', '136',
                     '191')
OPEN meuCursor 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 FETCH NEXT FROM meuCursor
       INTO
       @FIL_CODIGO                    ,
       @PRO_CODIGO                    ,
       @ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIAL             ,
       @ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIALPRODUCAO     , 
       @ETQ_ESTOQUEMINIMO             ,
       @ETQ_ESTOQUEMAXIMO             ,
       @ETQ_ESTOQUECOMPRADO           ,
       @ETQ_VALORULTIMOCUSTO          ,
       @ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRA          ,
       @ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDO         ,
       @ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIO      ,
       @ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRAMEDIO     ,
       @ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDOMEDIO    ,
       @ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIOMEDIO ,
       @ETQ_DATAULTIMAVENDA           ,
       @ETQ_VALORULTIMAVENDA          ,
       @ETQ_QUANTIDADEVENDIDA         ,
       @ETQ_DATAULTIMACOMPRA          ,
       @ETQ_VALORULTIMACOMPRA         ,
       @ETQ_QUANTIDADECOMPRADA        ,
       @ETQ_DATAALTERACAO             ;   

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
      SET @ETQ_ID = 
          (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ETQ_ID),0) + 1 
             FROM NESKI_DBA_ERP..ETQ_00)    

 INSERT INTO neski_dba_erp.dbo.Etq_00
 ( 
        ETQ_ID,
        FIL_CODIGO,
        PRO_CODIGO,
        ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIAL,
        ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIALPRODUCAO,
        ETQ_ESTOQUEMINIMO,
        ETQ_ESTOQUEMAXIMO,
        ETQ_ESTOQUECOMPRADO,
        ETQ_VALORULTIMOCUSTO,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRA,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDO,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIO,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRAMEDIO,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDOMEDIO,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIOMEDIO,
        ETQ_DATAULTIMAVENDA,
        ETQ_VALORULTIMAVENDA,
        ETQ_QUANTIDADEVENDIDA,
        ETQ_DATAULTIMACOMPRA,
        ETQ_VALORULTIMACOMPRA,
        ETQ_QUANTIDADECOMPRADA,
        ETQ_DATAALTERACAO
 )
 VALUES
(
        @ETQ_ID                        ,
        @FIL_CODIGO                    ,
        @PRO_CODIGO                    ,
        @ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIAL             ,
        @ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIALPRODUCAO     , 
        @ETQ_ESTOQUEMINIMO             ,
        @ETQ_ESTOQUEMAXIMO             ,
        @ETQ_ESTOQUECOMPRADO           ,
        @ETQ_VALORULTIMOCUSTO          ,
        @ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRA          ,
        @ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDO         ,
        @ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIO      ,
        @ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRAMEDIO     ,
        @ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDOMEDIO    ,
        @ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIOMEDIO ,
        @ETQ_DATAULTIMAVENDA           ,
        @ETQ_VALORULTIMAVENDA          ,
        @ETQ_QUANTIDADEVENDIDA         ,
        @ETQ_DATAULTIMACOMPRA          ,
        @ETQ_VALORULTIMACOMPRA         ,
        @ETQ_QUANTIDADECOMPRADA        ,
        @ETQ_DATAALTERACAO                  
)
END

CLOSE meuCursor
DEALLOCATE meuCursor
```

**SOLUÇÃO**

```
declare @Hoje datetime;
set @Hoje= cast(current_timestamp as date);

declare @Ult_ID int;
set @Ult_ID= coalesce ((SELECT max(ETQ_ID) from neski_dba_erp.dbo.Etq_00), 0);

INSERT INTO neski_dba_erp.dbo.Etq_00 with (tablock)
 (      
    ETQ_ID,
    FIL_CODIGO,
    PRO_CODIGO,
    ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIAL,
    ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIALPRODUCAO,
    ETQ_ESTOQUEMINIMO,
    ETQ_ESTOQUEMAXIMO,
    ETQ_ESTOQUECOMPRADO,
    ETQ_VALORULTIMOCUSTO,
    ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRA,
    ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDO,
    ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIO,
    ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRAMEDIO,
    ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDOMEDIO,
    ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIOMEDIO,
    ETQ_DATAULTIMAVENDA,
    ETQ_VALORULTIMAVENDA,
    ETQ_QUANTIDADEVENDIDA,
    ETQ_DATAULTIMACOMPRA,
    ETQ_VALORULTIMACOMPRA,
    ETQ_QUANTIDADECOMPRADA,
    ETQ_DATAALTERACAO
)
    SELECT @Ult_ID + row_number() over(order by (SELECT 0)), 
           '001', 
           substring (CODPRO,2,6), 
           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
           @Hoje, 0, 0, @Hoje, 0, 0, @Hoje
      from SAPIENS_HOM.dbo.E075PRO
     where CodFam in ('010', '015', '020', '025', '030', '040',
                     '042', '050', '052', '055', '060', '070',
                     '071', '075', '076', '077', '078', '100', 
                     '110', '120', '130', '140', '153', '160', 
                     '170', '180', '185', '190', '195', '115', 
                     '105', '199', '106', '125', '135', '136',
                     '191')
      AND CODPRO NOT IN ('3200380','0300310','0400330');
```

Comment: Se colocar de novo o `FETCH` no fim do ciclo `WHILE` não funciona?

Comment: mude seu ETQ_ID para identity remova do insert e seja feliz.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza nem mais!

Comment: Não posso fazer isso @MarconcilioSouza.

Comment: Vou tentar @JoãoMartins, avisarei aqui se deu certo.

Comment: Como estão declaradas as colunas `ETQ_DATAULTIMAVENDA`,        `ETQ_DATAULTIMACOMPRA` e `ETQ_DATAALTERACAO`?

Answer (score 3):

Eu acho que utilizar cursor para algo tão simples é complicar algo que pode ser resolvido com INSERT ... SELECT.

```
-- código #1
declare @Hoje datetime;
set @Hoje= cast(current_timestamp as date);

declare @Ult_ID int;
set @Ult_ID= coalesce ((SELECT max(ETQ_ID) from neski_dba_erp.dbo.Etq_00), 0);

INSERT INTO neski_dba_erp.dbo.Etq_00 with (tablock)
 (      ETQ_ID,
        FIL_CODIGO,
        PRO_CODIGO,
        ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIAL,
        ETQ_ESTOQUEFILIALPRODUCAO,
        ETQ_ESTOQUEMINIMO,
        ETQ_ESTOQUEMAXIMO,
        ETQ_ESTOQUECOMPRADO,
        ETQ_VALORULTIMOCUSTO,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRA,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDO,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIO,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOCOMPRAMEDIO,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOLIQUIDOMEDIO,
        ETQ_VALORCUSTOINVENTARIOMEDIO,
        ETQ_DATAULTIMAVENDA,
        ETQ_VALORULTIMAVENDA,
        ETQ_QUANTIDADEVENDIDA,
        ETQ_DATAULTIMACOMPRA,
        ETQ_VALORULTIMACOMPRA,
        ETQ_QUANTIDADECOMPRADA,
        ETQ_DATAALTERACAO
 )
SELECT @Ult_ID + row_number() over(order by (SELECT 0)), 
       '001', 
        substring (CODPRO,2,6), 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        @Hoje, 0, 0, @Hoje, 0, 0, @Hoje
  from SAPIENS_HOM.dbo.E075PRO
  where CodFam in ('010', '015', '020', '025', '030', '040',
                   '042', '050', '052', '055', '060', '070',
                   '071', '075', '076', '077', '078', '100', 
                   '110', '120', '130', '140', '153', '160', 
                   '170', '180', '185', '190', '195', '115', 
                   '105', '199', '106', '125', '135', '136',
                   '191');
```

Sugiro a leitura do artigo “Importação de dados em massa”, que está na seção Artigos do [Porto SQL](https://portosql.wordpress.com).

Comment: Deu super certo aqui, muito obrigado mesmo! :-)

Comment: @EduardoTeixeira Fica bem mais simples com INSERT ... SELECT. E mais rápido!